# How to select latest stable version of Kotlin Gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, version, dependency-management

I've been experimenting with selecting the "latest stable version" of Gradle-managed Kotlin dependencies. Starting from [the gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin#rejectversionsif-and-componentselection) I added this to my build.gradle:

```
    def isNonStable = { String version ->
      def stableKeyword = ['RELEASE', 'FINAL', 'GA'].any { it -> version.toUpperCase().contains(it) }
      def regex = /^[0-9,.v-]+(-r)?$/
      return !stableKeyword && !(version ==~ regex)
    }
    
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            componentSelection {
                all {
                    if (isNonStable(it.candidate.version)) {
                        reject('not a stable version')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which works as expected with most of my dependencies, rejecting for example "beta" versions - apart from Kotlin itself.

Relevant dependencies:

```
dependencies {    
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:[1.7.21, )')

    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
```

cli: `./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --dependency=kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`

If I set my Kotlin plugin to `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '[1.7.21, )'` then:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0-Beta FAILED
   Failures:
      - Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0-Beta.
```

Setting a range constraint on the plugin did not work! It did not seem to be subject to the reject declarations in the configuration, and I can't see any way to impose the same configuration on plugin version resolution.

I tried a few options - two resolved my issue:

- removing the plugin altogether (not an interesting solution, dependencies resolve correctly but my Kotlin stuff doesn't build!)
- setting the plugin version to something older than the constraint the bom

The latter option works well enough in the short term but it's a bit weird and unclear what's really happening.

Is there a better solution I'm missing?